# Which event handles object becoming/losing first responder status?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I have a UITextView, and I'd like to show UILabel once it receives First Responder status, and hide UILabel when UITextView loses it.

What action handles becoming/losing first responder? Or perhaps there is a better way to display UILabel only when UITextView has focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also the UITextFieldDelegate methods available to use.

```
(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

These will be called before and after the UITextField loses the first responder status.

Answer (score 6):

UIView is a subclass of UIResponder. Your view will be sent a `-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder` when it becomes first responder and `-(BOOL)resignFirstResponder` when it loses it. You can also perform some processing *before* both of these events from `–(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder` and `–(BOOL)canResignFirstResponder`. All of these methods are defined on UIResponder.

In all cases, assuming you do want to become (or resign) first responder, you should return YES to these messages.

Comment: Wow, that was a quick answer :) Do I understand correctly that I have to create my own class to catch this? Or is there some way to use delegates?

Comment: Yes, create a subclass of UITextView and implement these methods.